# Why is the loop terminating just after a single execution?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int x=0;
    while(n--)
    {
        char s[3];
        cin>>s;
        if(strcmp(s,"X++")==0||strcmp(s,"++X")==0)
        x+=1;
        else
        x-=1;
    }
    cout<<x;
}
```

The loop worked fine when I removed the strcmp line inside the if statement.

Comment: To store a string like `"X++"`, `s` must be at least of size 4.

Comment: Since you are using C++ why not use `std::string` instead of a character array for your input. Comparison will also be more natural like `if(s=="X++" || ...`

Answer (score 0):

Like πάντα ῥεῖ said, the size of ***s*** must be 4 in order to store the '\0' character. Otherwise :

```
cin >> s;    // For example write "X++"
```

will store your string in ***s*** and put '\0' out of the bounds of ***s***.

When the program goes in the loop for the second time, you won't be able to write it because it will get "" (an empty string) every time.
To fix that, just replace **3** with **4** and that will be OK.

**Note** :  If you really want to use C++, I suggest you to use std::string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int x = 0;

    while(n--)
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        if(s == "X++" || s == "++X")
            x+=1;
        else
            x-=1;
    }
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```